# Track application id or package name using DatagramPacket in android

Tags: android, android-networking, android-vpn-service

I open a socket and track network calls in the Android application. Currently, I can view the hostname and IP address of the coming network traffic using the `DatagramPacket` class. Is it possible to get the `application id` or `package name` using it? Or is it possible to get the `application ID` or `package name` from IPPacket in DNSResolver?

Answer (score 0):

After a long search and reading documentation of Android related to networks, I found the solution to get the application ID that the OS assigns. Through this ID it's possible to find the network packet's source. It's not possible to get the package name through `DatagramPacket` or any network calls.

The ID is an integer before comparing the ID it's important to get the application ID which was assigned by the OS using `PackageManager`.

```
val local = InetSocketAddress(sourceHostAddress, sourcePort)
val remote = InetSocketAddress(destinationHostAddress, destinationPort)
val connectivityManager = instance.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager;
val uId = connectivityManager.getConnectionOwnerUid(protocol, local, remote);
```

**Protocol**
TCP = 6
UDP = 17